# Matplotlib Animation, Either Runs Slow and Replots Colorbar, or Missing Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am attempting to animate data that I have previously saved by loading the `numpy` array for each frame.

My code is as follows:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, constrained_layout = False)

def routine(omega):
    omega_plot = ax.pcolormesh(x_grid, y_grid, omega, cmap = 'coolwarm')
    
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2 * np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 2 * np.pi) 

    divider = make_axes_locatable(omega_plot.axes)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size = "5%", pad = 0.2)
    fig.colorbar(omega_plot, cax = cax, orientation = 'vertical')
    cax.set_ylabel(r"$\mathrm{mag}\left[ \vec{u} \right]$")

    ax.set_title(r"$\omega(t)")
    # some plot routine parts excluded

    return ax

def init():
    omega = np.load("pcolor Animation/temp/omega_ana, n = 0.npy")
    return routine(omega)

def update(n):
    print(n)
    omega = np.load("pcolor Animation/temp/omega_ana, n = {0}.npy".format(n))
    return routine(omega)

ANI = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames = range(0, 2000, 10), init_func = init)
ANI.save("pcolor Animation/Taylor-Greene Vortex Animation.mp4", fps = 180, dpi = 200)
```

When I run it, I get the following:[image: Colorbar Drift]
Now, this is actually correct. Taylor-Greene flow exponentially decays but otherwise does not change, but it is also obvious that the colorbar is being replotted each time, leading to a 'drift'. Additionally, the code slows down with each frame, because it is plotting on top of the previous ones.

If we add `plt.clf()` or `fig.clear()` or any of the other suggestions that various Stack Overflow answers suggest about `matplotlib.animation`s to the top of `routine(omega)`, we get the following:
[image: Missing Plot]
This time, our colorbar is correct, and the animation runs much more quickly, but the data itself is missing.

What am I missing? I've done my due diligence and have tried to fix this problem with the suggestions on various other similar questions, and have been having this problem for a few days. I'd appreciate any help, and thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you want to happen?  Do you want the colorbar to be constant and the pcolormesh colours to fade out?  Or do you want the pcolormesh to look constant but the colorbar labels to drift like you show in your last gif?

Comment: @RuthC, though my exact use case is the second, where the colorbar labels actively update, could you provide an example for both? I think it'd be extremely helpful to both myself and future Stack Overflow users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the animation efficiently, we want to update as little as possible.  So create the artists up front, and then just update the array used in the `QuadMesh` artist (which is returned from `pcolormesh`).  Also updating the norm that the `QuadMesh` uses will make the colorbar's range change.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
omega_plot = ax.pcolormesh(np.zeros((10, 10)), cmap='Blues', vmin=0, vmax=100)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

divider = make_axes_locatable(omega_plot.axes)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size = "5%", pad = 0.2)
fig.colorbar(omega_plot, cax = cax, orientation = 'vertical')
cax.set_ylabel(r"$\mathrm{mag}\left[ \vec{u} \right]$")

ax.set_title(r"$\omega(t)$")


def update(n):
    omega = np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10) * 0.99**n
    omega_plot.set_array(omega)
    
    # Change the valid range of the data (remove this line for the colorbar to be constant).
    omega_plot.set_norm(Normalize(vmin=omega.min(), vmax=omega.max()))


ANI = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames = range(0, 200, 10))
ANI.save("test.gif", fps = 10)
```

The above code produces

[image]

If we remove the last line of the `update` function, we instead get

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't previously aware you could change the data values that the plot was using as follows: `omega_plot.set_array(omega)`. This works great for dynamically updating `pcolor[mesh]` plots and their colorbar.

Comment: Is there a similar way to modify the arrays that `ax.quiver()` plots? Using `set_array` on the `ax.quiver()` object doesn't seem to work

Comment: There is `Quiver.set_UVC` https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.quiver.Quiver.html#matplotlib.quiver.Quiver.set_UVC